# An umbrella is made by stitching $10$ triangular pieces. How much cloth of each color is required?

Tags: geometry

An umbrella is made by stitching $10$ triangular pieces, of cloth of two different colors, each piece measuring $20$ $cm$ long, $50$ $cm$ and $50$ $cm$. How much cloth of each color is required for the umbrella?

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjA1w.jpg)

Comment: doesn't look like the question is complete. What 2 colors. What exact dimensions.

Comment: The two colors are different. Say, one color is red and the other blue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count the number of triangles of each color, and use [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to compute the area of one triangle.

I notice that the umbrella has an angle deficit of almost $130°$. So disregarding the elasticity of the cloth, it would form a cone where opposite lines at the apex form an angle of less than $80°$, unless I made a mistake in my calculation. I would feel somewhat uncomfortable under such a high but narrow umbrella! But none of this is required to answer the question, just shows that the numbers probably didn't come out of actual umbrella production. Or it was umbrellas for little kids.

Comment: You need to find the area and not the number of cloths.

Comment: @You need to find the *total* area, which is the number of pieces times the area of each piece. Unless you also take the arrangement of triangles on the original piece of cloth into account, and the parts you'll need to cut away.

Answer (score 0):

You need not 10 but at least 15 pieces of the such a triangular cloth. As @MvG said above, If you use 10 there is a deficit of $130^\circ$. How? Because of the dimension of such a triangle 50*50*20, the apex angle comes out to be $\approx 23^\circ$. Taking $24^\circ$ for a simple calculation you need $\frac{360^\circ}{24^\circ}=15$ pieces.

Comment: But an umbrella isn't flat, and a cone might be a reasonable first approximation. If the triangle edges are slightly rounded, the umbrella will become curved.